# Piccolo note duration

Tags: physical-limitations, breathing, piccolo

I'm writing a wind ensemble piece and have a piccolo holding a long note that transitions from one section to the next. Quarter note = 64 bpm, and the pic holds G5 for 7 beats, or about 6.6 seconds. The long note serves to end a phrase in one section and begin the opening phrase in the next. I should add that after the long note, there are several good places to sneak a breath.
The performers are high school level, but good high school.  I can't whistle the note that long, but I'm not a wind player.  Is this a reasonable length? My back up plan is to have flutes 1 and 2 double the pic and stagger their breathing.  [image]

Comment: Have you done any research?  Do you have access to the piccolo player to ask directly?  After all, if you're writing for a specific group, more important than the ability of piccolo players generally is the ability of the piccolo player for whom you are writing.

Answer (score 1):

I concur with @Aaron.

From personal experience, thinking back to when I was in high school, holding a G5 for 6.6 seconds is no problem, especially since this G5 is in the easiest register to play on the piccolo. Compared to whistling, the size of the embouchure hole is a lot smaller on the piccolo, so a lot less air is used. (I must admit that I cannot whistle, though.)

Answer (score 0):

A single, sustained pitch of 7 seconds should be no problem for a proficient high-school flautist.

Comment: Why should we believe you?  Personal experience?  Objective evidence?  Relevant information from some authoritative source?  I don't doubt that this answer is correct, but without knowing the basis for its assertion, the answer carries very little weight.